# When I add Key value Dictionary in Key Value Dictionary of NsMutableArray at Position of 0. it will be throw in Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

[image]

Below is my Code, When I Add Dictionary into NSMutableArray that time it works well but when I Put NSLog It will throw an Exception. So, Please Help me

```
        //-->
        arrMain = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *arrMainMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *arrMainMenu2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < arrParent.count; i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dictMain = [arrParent objectAtIndex:i];
            if([[dictMain valueForKey:E_UNDER] isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSString *titleMain = [dictMain valueForKey:E_PARAMETER_VALUE_NAME];
                NSMutableArray *arrSubMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int j = 0; j <arrSub.count; j++)
                {
                    NSMutableDictionary *dictSub = [[arrSub objectAtIndex:j] mutableCopy];
                    if([titleMain isEqualToString:[dictSub valueForKey:E_UNDER]])
                        [arrSubMenu addObject:dictSub];
                }

                if([arrSubMenu count])
                {
                    [dictMain setValue:@"1" forKey:IS_EXAPANDABLE];
                    [dictMain setValue:@"0" forKey:IS_EXPANDED];
                    [arrSubMenu insertObject:dictMain atIndex:0]; //Here Add Key-Value Dictionary in Array
                    [dictMain setValue:arrSubMenu forKey:LIST_ID];
                    arrSubMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                else
                    [dictMain setValue:@"0" forKey:IS_EXAPANDABLE];
                [arrMainMenu addObject:dictMain];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", arrMainMenu); //Here Throw Bad Access exception
        [obj_DataModel setFilterMenu:arrMainMenu];
        //-->
```

Comment: What does the console says?

Comment: check that array have some object or not

Comment: Yes, Array have some object that add dictionary into it.